# Is there a uniformly equicontinuous sequence $f_n$ that doesn't converge uniformly on a compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a theorem that says that if $f_n:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ converge uniformly then it is uniformly equicontinuous. I was wondering if the converse is true or not, and if no, could you give e a counter example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Take $f_n(x)=n$, for each $x\in[a,b]$. It is clear that it is uniformly equicontinuous (just take $\delta=\varepsilon$), but it converges uniformly nowhere (since it converges nowhere).

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit more fun if you add some assumption to your sequence -- like "$f_n(c)$ is bounded for some $c\in [a,b]$". In that case the answer is implied by the [theorem of Arzela and Ascoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).

(Note that boundedness in one single point and equicontinuity on a compact connected intervall implies uniform boundedness)